# Make mouse events on JComponent after transform work?

Tags: java, transform, scale, mouselistener, jcomponent

Hello and sorry for my imperfect English.

I have a class `MyNode` (draws a rectangle) that extends `JComponent`. I have mouse listener for `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` to change its color.
The big problem is that i need to work with transforms (the main app, not this SSCE, it is a graph (nodes&edges) drawer.)
I read about this problem already but I want to ask you how can i make it work. If I apply a `scale(2,2)` on my panel i have two main problems:

1. The mouse position doesn't correspond anymore to the drew `MyNode`. I know i can apply `inverseTransform` and this works just well, but I must search in **all** node collection of the panel and check the `contains` method with the inversed point (inefficient imo). (hope you get what i am saying here). How i can make the `mouseEntered`, `mouseExited` etc. work by itself in the new scaled system.
2. If I scale the panel, the MyNode `paintComponent()` doesn't apply its owner `(Panel)` transforms. The node is drew with its initial size.

I am very curious if this can be resolved, and I wait any other question to help you understand what I am looking for. It seems even hard to explain the problem, can't imagine the solution :)

This is a demo of my problem (you can run it):

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;

import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class SSCE extends JPanel {

  public SSCE() {
    setLayout(null);
    setBackground(Color.yellow);
    setSize(new Dimension(500, 300));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 200));
    add(new MyNode(0, 0));
    setVisible(true);
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2d.scale(2, 2);
    super.paintComponent(g2d);
    paintComponents(g2d);
  }

}

class MyNode extends JComponent {

  private Color activeColor = Color.red;

  public MyNode(int x, int y) {
    this.setLocation(x, y);
    this.setSize(50, 50);

    this.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

      @Override
      public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
        colorOnMouseHover();
      }

      @Override
      public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
        colorOnMouseLeave();
      }

    });
  }

  private void colorOnMouseHover() {
    this.activeColor = Color.blue;
    repaint();
  }

  private void colorOnMouseLeave() {
    this.activeColor = Color.red;
    repaint();
  }

  @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.setColor(activeColor);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, 50, 50);
  }
}

class Run {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();
    frame.setSize(500, 200);
    frame.add(new SSCE());
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```